# Как получить максимальное значение массива в js ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы

Пытаюсь получить максимальное значение элемента массива средствами JavaScript:

На сервере массив формируется следующим образом:

```
$usr = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($usr)) { 
  $products_code_arr[] = $row[0];
}                
echo $products_code_arr;
```

print_r показывает, что имеем массив вида

```
Array ( [0] => 1237 [1] => 234 )
```

Забираю его ajax-ом и пытаюсь найти максимальное значение :

```
var url = 'get_data.php'; 
  $.post(          
    url,
    function(data) {
      var arr = data;
      function getMax(arr){
        return Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
      }

      var max = getMax(arr);
    );
```

Способ описан [здесь](http://javascript.ru/blog/ixth/minmax-dlya-massivov), но у меня он не работает, получаю ошибку: *Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object*

Прошу подсказать, где ошибка и как её исправить.

Comment: В обработчике `$.post` добавьте строчку `console.log(data)` и посмотрите, что выведется в консоль.

Comment: У метода `$.post()` вторым параметром должен быть объект со значениями вида `{ a: 'b', c: 'd' }`, у вас же функция(она должна быть третьей).

Comment: P.S. Вы передаете массив `php` в `js`, на что вы надеетесь?

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко, выводится "Array"

Comment: @mix, вы правы насчет второго параметра, но у меня в других участках кода эта конструкция работает. Насколько я понимаю, проблема все же в другом, тем более что ответ я получаю. А вот почему не могу его прочесть - это, действительно, вопрос. Я не утверждаю, что я прав (я новичок), но думаю так.

Comment: @118_64 Если выводится "Array", значит что-то не так. В консоль должно выводиться *содержимое* массива. Возможно, в PHP вы как-то неправильно сериализуете массив. Покажите код, которым вы массив отправляете из PHP в ответе ajax-запроса.

Comment: Говорю же, вы пытаетесь передать пхпшный массив в js, поэтому и не получается. Вы должны сделать из массива `JSON` объект, потом только передавать. На счет метода `$.post()` - если вы не отправляете никакие пост запросы, то лучше использовать метод `$.get()` или `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: ДмитрийШевченко, @mix, исправил (echo json_encode($products_code_arr)), но ошибка продолжает выводиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. У тебя на сервере формируется массив, но ты его не преобразовываешь. Если ты добавишь `echo json_encode($products_code_arr);`, то массив будет вида [12,3,4,15,2] и тогда все заработает. А иначе, ты выводишь на сервере строку "Array"

**Как было до преобразования:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 155
)
```

**Как стало:**

```
[15,2,155]
```

**Так же поправить ajax запрос:**

```
...
   function(data) {
      // Парсим строку json и преобразуем в массив чисел
      var arr = JSON.parse(data).map(function (el) { return parseInt(el); });
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, исправил и получил массив. Но ошибка остается: Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Comment: У себя проверил, все работает, выведите в консоль пришедший массив, напиши, посмотрим.

Comment: в консоли - ["1237","234"]

Comment: все просто, у тебя теперь каждый элемент стал строкой. Максимальное можно найти только от числа. Перед тем как закидывать массив в метод, преобразуй его так : `data.map(function (el) { return parseInt(el);})`

Comment: есть какая-то проблема или с массивом, которую я не вижу, или с синтаксисом. Пытался скормить массив методу, указанному вами и не смог: var new_arr = data.map(function (el) {  return parseInt(el); }); - Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function. Даже элементарное действие var new_arr = data.map(Math.sqrt); дает такую же ошибку

Comment: Я догадаюсь что сначала надо сделать JSON.parse(data).map..., других вариантов я пока не вижу, надо дебажить)

Comment: Приветствую.
А как строку `var new_arr = data.map(function (el) { return parseInt(el); }); ` пытались скормить?

Comment: Василий Барбашев, var arr = JSON.parse(data).map(function (el) { return parseInt(el); }); заработало! Спасибо за помощь. Укажите в вашем ответе и я отмечу его как решение вопроса.

Comment: @118_64 Поправил